# How to link an Input Control to a report's Parameter

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I'm unable to link an Input Control to my report's Parameter. I feel I'm doing right, but I can't see the desired result in the final report.

My intention is to create a list, filled by some options, and display the list in a report as a parameter, so the user can (multi)select the options. As far as I know, I must create an Input Control on the server, create a Parameter on the report using the same name between the Input Control and the Parameter.

I've created a List of Values named ListaCalificaciones as follows:

[image]

Then, this is the Input Control:

[image]

Finally, this is the parameter:

[image]

However, when it comes to show the report on Jasper Server's web interface, I can't see a filled input:

[image]

Am I missing something?

By the way, I'm using Jasper Studio 6.6.0 and Jasper Server 7.1.0 (compiled version 20180504_1307).

*Edit 2018/10/05 13:04*
I've changed the input control, so that the id is `ic_calificaciones` and the name stays as it was (`Calificaciones`). I've found a way to make it work. First, I deploy the report to my server (local server in my case). Then, I edit the report, go to "Controls and resources", remove the ic_calificaciones parameter and add a InputControl parameter to the report. That way the Calificaciones parameter gets filled up with options.

Comment: Please add your solution as answer instead of as an edit to your question.

Comment: @PetterFriberg The solution is not 2018/10/05's edit, it was somehow a workaround. Anyway, I'm posting the real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was just in front, but due to a poor UI I just didn't realise...

You must edit your parameter's name to match the Input Control's name, in my case it ought to be `ic_valoracion`. Then, the parameter-to-input-control-binding has to be made when publishing the report to the server.

So, being in Jasper Studio, click on publish button, as seen in the following picture:
[image]

Now, select the location where to publish the report. Then, the second step is what we're looking for, it's the place where you must select the resources to publish. As seen in the next image, you must edit your parameter's type to select "Link To Resource", click on whichever place and a new prompt will appear. Now, there, select the desired Input Control.
[image]

Finally, test your report.